# Apache doesn't start in AMPPS on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, terminal, localserver, ampps

I'm trying to run the Ampps local server 3.8 on Ubuntu. Mysql works good but apache doen't run.

When I type

> /usr/local/ampps/apache/bin/httpd

I get

> /usr/local/ampps/apache/bin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/ampps/apache/lib/libapr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: dlopen

How to solve?

Comment: Ok, I had the same issue I resolve with this answer. [Ampps Solution Apache Don't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013891/apache-doesnt-start-in-ampps-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Ok, I use this method and work after that [Solution Apache Does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013891/apache-doesnt-start-in-ampps-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem. Firstly you must check is there anything that uses 80 port. 
[image: netstat terminal screenshot]

If any you kill that.

Then you backup libapr and then install libs again.
Run following commands:

```
cd /usr/local/ampps/apache/lib

sudo mkdir backup

sudo mv ./libapr* ./backup/

sudo apt-get -y install libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dev libapr1 libapr1-dev
```

and try run ampps.

Comment: Works perfect! After running `netstat nlt` tcp6 was not listed as highlighted in your case,but it worked anyway.

Comment: Thats right. Maybe your 80 ports are not full and your some depency libraries are missing.

Comment: thanks ,wow  linux is really alot of work, i well appreciate if fixing  error after another. thanks man